# Fading the cursor

Tags: windows, qt

I have a Windows application for which I would like to indicate that the content is dead/frozen/not interactable by fading it to 50%.

Is there a way to take the standard Windows cursor and fade it?

Comment: That would look a bit odd/confusing imo; what about the standard Qt::ForbiddenCursor ?

Comment: It's HORRIBLE! No, seriously, I don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen a case of the Windows cursor being anything but 100% opaque, and I heavily suspect that there's no option to make it transparent because the uses are limited and the abuses are many (i.e. make cursor invisible, would cause massive frustration).

Comment: That's not true - Qt does offer the option and it makes a lot of sense in some situations (think of a touch display!!!)

Comment: @Jens: Where/how does Qt offer the option to make the cursor transparent?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do that, and it makes sense there's none - it is not a part of Window's look and feel. You'd usually fade the dead/frozen/not interactable control rather than the cursor, and/or change the cursor to a standard hourglass or so.

Having that say, if fading the cursor is definitively what you want, you can create a faded image of the standard cursor, and load it when needed.